# Inserting selected number of zeros between fixed number of non-zero elements in a vector in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, vector

I have a vector like 
       `A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`
I would like to insert 2 zero every 5 number.
The result would be `A=[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,6,7,8,9,10,0,0]`.

I know I could preallocate the space and then use a for cycle to assign the variable, but I was wandering if there was some more elegant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works even if `A` doesn't contain an integer number of blocks:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]; % input vector
m = 5; % block size
n = 2; % number of zeros to be added after each block
B = zeros(1, numel(A)+floor(numel(A)/m)*n); % preallocate to appropriate size
B(mod(0:end-1, m+n)<m) = A; % logical index. Fill values of A at desired positions of B
```

The result in this example is

```
B =
     1   2   3   4   5   0   0   6   7   8   9  10   0   0  11  12
```

Comment: Thanks is correct. Supposing now I don't have an integer number of block of size m? I should append some zeros at the end of the vector or still there is a better solution?

Comment: If the number of blocks is non-integer the problem is undefined. What would the desired output be in that case?

Comment: You are right. Let's say I have a vector 'A= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]' and I would like to have two zeros after every five number. The expected result would be 'A=[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,6,7,8,9,10,0,0,11]'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `A` having number of elements a multiple of `5`, you could use some reshaping and concatenation with `zeros`, like so -

```
reshape([reshape(A,5,[]) ; zeros(2,numel(A)/5)],1,[])
```